# Javascript Function taking an array as an argument and returns the count of odd elements of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm new to Javascript and I am taking a course on it. I got a task to create a function which is meant to take array as an agrument(no specific array or his elements are given), to count the number of odd elements and return the quantity of odd elements.

So I did something like this but the task does not seem to be fulfilled. What is wrong here?

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
   if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0)
       count++;
       return count++;
}
}
```

Comment: Why return `count++`? Remove the `++`; that mutation is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning early in your code

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
   if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0)
       count++;
       return count++; // Here you return when you find the first odd and exit the function so other odds are not counted for
   }
}
```

You need to return the count after the loop is done

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
   if(arr[i] % 2 !== 0)
       count++;
 
    }
    return count;
}
```

An other way to count the odd elements and get their total num of occurences would be to use Array.prototype#filter and the length like this :

```js
function count_odd_nums(arr){
  var count = arr.filter(item => item % 2 !== 0).length
  return count;
}

console.log(count_odd_nums([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
```

What it does  is the following. It uses Array#filter method to filter elements in the array executed based on a predicate function. In our case the predicate function checks whether a number is odd or not. It then return a new array containing the elements that passed our predicate function (in our case all odd nums). After that we can simply use the `.length` method of that array to find out how many odd nums we found

Take a look at the MDN for Array.prototype#filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter